# Arc for Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, cdi, quarkus

Is there a way to have a ArC CDI-Container in Unit-Tests without using the full force of @QuarkusTest, analogous to [weld-junit](https://github.com/weld/weld-junit) for weld? I'd rather not start up my whole application for a unit-test, but sometimes I need a CDI container, say if I want to test Interceptors and Decorators. Given that ArC is (intentionally) not fully compatible to the CDI spec, I'd rather test against the CDI container that will also be used in production than against weld.

Comment: There's an internal class `ArcTestContainer` that you may use. Stability is not guaranteed though.

Comment: Currently it is not possible, see this: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/12512

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference: Since 2023 there is [@QuarkusComponentTest](https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-component-test/) which does what I needed back then.